# What is the proper quoting to assign an interpolated sqlite3 query to a variable in Bash?

Tags: bash, sqlite, shell, quoting

I am trying to assign the output of the following to a variable

```
sqlite3 /home/user/db_fake_book_index "select id, page from fb2 where bookcode='$bookcode' and page=$page
```

If I run quote it like

```
echo "sqlite3 /home/user/db_fake_book_index \"select id, page from fb2 where bookcode='$bookcode' and page=$page\""
```

I get

```
sqlite3 /home/user/db_fake_book_index "select id, page from fb2 where bookcode='557S' and page=10"
```

and if I copy it to a console it works fine, but if i encase it in $() in my script it does not work, sqlite believes there are too many variables, it seems my double quotes are being removed.

```
$(printf "sqlite3 /home/user/db_fake_book_index \"select id, page from fb2 where bookcode='$bookcode' and page=$page\"")
```

This gives the same faliure

Comment: So what's wrong with running it as the first example shows, without `echo`, `printf` and `$()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
result=$( sqlite3 /home/user/db_fake_book_index "select id, page from fb2 where bookcode='$bookcode' and page=$page" )
```

or

```
query="select id, page from fb2 where bookcode='$bookcode' and page=$page"
result=$( sqlite3 /home/user/db_fake_book_index "$query" )
```

Comment: just fix `sqllite3` (double "l") typos

Comment: Looking at this 4 1/2 years later, I’d really like to address the potential for SQL injection, but I won’t have that chance for a while, and will probably forget about it. Reader, beware.

Answer (score 0):

This will save as the variable `v`

```sh
set "select id, page from fb2 where bookcode='$bookcode' and page=$page"
read v < <(sqlite3 /home/user/db_fake_book_index "$1")
```